# How to delete records in a table which are created between a particular time window?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have this requirement of deleting records from a table which are created daily from 9AM to 11PM. I have figured out something like this -

```
delete * FROM mytable 
WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(entry_date,'HH24MI')) BETWEEN 0900 AND 2300;
```

However this deletes all records which are created in the time window, whereas I want it only for the current day. How can I use the sysdate here ? Or is there any other approach ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dropped the date part, you should do something like this

```
DELETE * FROM mytable WHERE entry_date BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE)+9/24 and trunc(SYSDATE)+23/24
```

I used 9/24 and 23/24 because of date arithmetic works with days, so the 9/24 is 9 hours.